# How to use older version of Solidity in Truffle suite

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract

I've tried to migrate contract on an older version of solidity, I have modified the config.js to be as in the following 
[image]

and the smart contract solidity code I'm trying to deploy as follows
 [image]

The problem is that whenever I try to migrate the contract it displays the following error.
[image]

any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `^` from truffle-config.js.

You want to tell truffle which version to use. The "or higher" notion only applies to `pragma` in Solidity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your solution it's solved.